# Windows 8 Storage Space Error

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, storage-spaces

I have a Storage Space set up with 2 way mirroring on Windows Pro 8.1. It has 4 Hard drives. 2x2TB 640GB and 1.5TB. The 1.5TB has a bad sector and every time windows tries to read it, any process associated with that drive freezes up until reboot. So I bought a new 2TB to replace the 1.5. I now have 5 Hard drives plugged in and I cannot remove the 1.5 from the Storage Space "Drive could not be removed because not all data could be reallocated. Add an additional drive to this pool and reattempt this operation."

[image]

If I start up the computer without the drive it does not let me access the storage space. I believe what is happening is when it tried to rebuild the Storage space on the new 2TB it freezes up on the bad sector. How can I remove the 1.5TB from the storage space?

[image]

In this configuration my Storage Space is accessible but freezes up and there is constant hard drive activity without any transfer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching and searching I discovered there is nothing I can do. I copied what I could onto another Hard Drive and deleted the Storage Space and Started from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the system is looking for a new drive to replace your 1.5 TB drive, so the raid can be re-generated.  Add the new drive first, then when it has been successfully added to the pool, you can then remove the "retired" drive.

Comment: I already have added the new drive. It is the last one on the screen shot I provided.